# How to pop up a GTK window/widget on top of a full screen application of a different process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, gtk, gnome, display-manager

System information - Debian 8 with gnome display manager.

I have two process - say 'A' and 'B'. 'A' is running as a full screen application and another process 'B' is started. All that B does is it creates a GTK widget and displays it. I am trying to display this widget on top of a full screen application 'A' but somehow it's  coming  behind and not on top of 'A'.

I have a gnome display manager and I believe that this display manager is blocking the process B to pop up a window on another full screen running application/process A.

Could someone help me on how I can make B to pop up a window on top of A?
Need a implementation in C language for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to integrate B into the window manager somehow, and not make it as a standalone application. For security reasons, most window managers don't allow applications to pop up their windows on top of other applications' windows. The reason for this is that it would be easy to make a malicious application to confuse a user and perhaps steal their personal information.